# How to nest ng-repeat with two related entities

Tags: angularjs

I have two entities:

- OrderOpened
- ProductOrdered with relation:

  relationship ManyToOne {
      ProductOrdered {Order} to OrderOpened
  }

I need to list Orders with related Products in one view.

No problem with Orders:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="orderOpened in vm.orderOpeneds track by orderOpened.id">
    <td><a ui-sref="order-opened-detail({id:orderOpened.id})">{{orderOpened.id}}</a></td>
    <td>
        <a ui-sref="desk-detail({id:orderOpened.desk.id})">{{orderOpened.desk.description}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{orderOpened.openingTime | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
    <td>{{orderOpened.user.login}}</td>
   [...]
 </tr>
```

But then I want to nest Products related to this Order like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="productOrdered in vm.productOrdereds track by productOrdered.id">
   <td><a ui-sref="product-ordered-detail({id:productOrdered.id})">{{productOrdered.id}}</a></td>
   <td>{{productOrdered.orderedTime | date:'medium'}}</td>
  [...]
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
[...]
function loadAll() {
    OrderOpened.query(function(result) {
        vm.orderOpeneds = result; //works
        angular.forEach(vm.orderOpeneds, function(productOrdered) {
            TestOrderOpened.query({id:productOrdered.id}, function(result2) { 
                //in java: List<ProductOrdered> productOrdereds = productOrderedRepository.findAllByOrderId(id);
                vm.productOrdereds = result2;
            })
        })
    });
 }
```

In result I get products related only to last iteration of angular.forEach, not related to current Order.

How can I pass productOrdered.id to ng-repeat directive or use another way to get related entities in one view?

Comment: Do you want something dynamic like when user click one order, the related products are displayed ? or do you want to display the list of product for each order in the list right ahead ?

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is normal:
In your controller, you have 2 lists defined:

- `vm.orderOpeneds`
- `vm.productOrdereds`

With this, you can only display one list of `productOrdereds`, which happens to be the one of the last loaded order.

If you want to display the list of products for each order, you have to store them somewhere. Several solutions:

1) In each loaded order, store the related products, i.e.

```
function loadAll() {
    OrderOpened.query(function(result) {
        vm.orderOpeneds = result; //works
        angular.forEach(vm.orderOpeneds, function(productOrdered) {
            TestOrderOpened.query({id:productOrdered.id}, function(result2) { 
                //in java: List<ProductOrdered> productOrdereds = productOrderedRepository.findAllByOrderId(id);
                // CHANGE: here store the products in the order
                productOrdered.productOrdereds = result2;
            })
        })
    });
}
```

2) Or buid a separate collection like a map whose keys are the order id and the values the list of associated products

```
var productsByOrderId = {}

function loadAll() {
    OrderOpened.query(function(result) {
        vm.orderOpeneds = result; //works
        angular.forEach(vm.orderOpeneds, function(productOrdered) {
            TestOrderOpened.query({id:productOrdered.id}, function(result2) { 
                //in java: List<ProductOrdered> productOrdereds = productOrderedRepository.findAllByOrderId(id);
                // CHANGE: here store the products in the map
                productsByOrderId[productOrdered.id] = result2;
            })
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind product with your orders.

```
 var results = [];
 function loadAll() {
   OrderOpened.query(function(result) {
   vm.orderOpeneds = result; //works
   angular.forEach(vm.orderOpeneds, function(productOrdered) {
        TestOrderOpened.query({id:productOrdered.id}, function(result2) { 
          // bind your product with orders
          productOrdered.productOrdereds = result2;
         // then
          results.push(productOrdered);
        });
    });
   vm.orderOpeneds = results;
  });
}
```